# How I can test arguments in Observable RxJava

Tags: java, kotlin, testing, rx-java

I have some method:

```
repository.get(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Method return `Single<List<SomeObject>>`

I need testing that Single was called `onSubscribe()` with specific arguments.

```
repository.get(arg1, arg2, arg3)
            .test()
            .assertSubscribed()
```

This method ignores arguments which I put in method `repository.get()`.

How I can test that subscribe called with certain arguments?

Answer (score 1):

use `Schedulers.trampoline()` to make the subscription occur on the current thread. then you can assert the required args

```
@Before
    fun setup() {
        RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
        RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
    }
```

this makes the code run on the current thread.
then you can assert the args

```
repository.get(arg1, arg2, arg3)
            .test()
            .subscribe {
                 // do the assertions here
             }
```

Comment: You probably misunderstood me. I need check that arg1, arg2, arg3 is correct. And i no need testing emitted data. Only that suscribe() was called and i have correct arguments (arg1, arg2, arg3)

Comment: subscribe doesn't know about arg1, arg2, arg3 only knows about the response. RxJava is used for your result not your input. you need to mock whatever it is that your repository calling. and then check if the arguments are correctly passed to that object

Comment: I know that subscribe doesn`t know about arg1... But I don`t know how I can test that method was called with correct arguments. When i call verify on method get(arg1, arg2, arg3) I receive calling method when I create an Observable. But at this moment I`m not subscribe to Observable

Comment: first, provide code for your repository, then I will try to understand what you want to test